# Invalid object name 'table'

Tags: django, active-directory, django-auth-ldap

I have a few bases in my project. Hence I need to redefine methods which get some information from base. Everything had worked fine until I decided to authorize via active directory. Finally I get this: authorization works (default database), requests to database that is not default fails. Authorization info is stored in PostgreSQL database. Data is stored in MSSQL database. Django-ajax-datatable is response for render data from MSSQL database.

I get error ProgrammingError at /admin/app/table/

('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'table'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/app/table/

Django Version: 3.2.14
Python Version: 3.10.5
Installed Applications:
['app.apps.CrmConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'debug_toolbar',
'django_filters',
'bootstrap3',
'ajax_datatable']
Installed Middleware:
['debug_toolbar.middleware.Debu gToolbarMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.Se curityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middl eware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.Comm onMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfVi ewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middlewar e.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middl eware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjackin g.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 598, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

The above exception (('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name 'table'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")) was the direct cause of the following exception:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 616, in wrapper
return self.admin_site.admin_view(vie w)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 44, in _wrapped_view_func
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 232, in inner
return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1697, in changelist_view
cl = self.get_changelist_instance(r equest)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 736, in get_changelist_instance
return ChangeList(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 100, in __init__
self.get_results(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/views/main.py", line 235, in get_results
result_count = paginator.count
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/paginator.py", line 97, in count
return c()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 412, in count
return self.query.get_count(using=sel f.db)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 528, in get_count
number = obj.get_aggregation(using, ['__count'])['__count']
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 513, in get_aggregation
result = compiler.execute_sql(SINGLE)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1175, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 230, in execute
return self._record(self.cursor.execu te, sql, params) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 154, in _record
return method(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 98, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 66, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sq l, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in _execute
with self.db.wrap_database_errors:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(tr aceback) from exc_value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/mssql/base.py", line 598, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

Exception Type: ProgrammingError at /admin/app/table/
Exception Value: ('42S02', "[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL 
Server]Invalid object name 'table'. (208) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

As for me there is nothing interesting in my traceback so can you say anything? What can cause this error? AThere is nothing connected with data in MSSQL database in django-auth-ldap.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with environment variables in docker-compose. Facepalm

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).